# OAuth Exception in Facebook messenger chatbot using api.ai and heroku(node.js)

Tags: node.js, facebook, heroku, dialogflow-es, facebook-chatbot

I have shared my code and the error that popped up below. Basically, I followed the tutorial http://www.girliemac.com/blog/2017/01/06/facebook-apiai-bot-nodejs/ and another one. My chatbot works for smalltalk but not for the weather api stuff. I am trying to make the chatbot give me answers about the weather in different cities. I have followed the tutorial exactly.

```
  Error:  { message: '(#100) No matching user found',
  type: 'OAuthException',
   code: 100,
  error_subcode: 2018001,
   fbtrace_id: 'DeubaTWU6Gg' }
 Error:  { message: '(#100) No matching user found',
   type: 'OAuthException',
   code: 100,
   error_subcode: 2018001,
   fbtrace_id: 'FSiMes3IwHv' }
```

//code from index.js just for weather api stuff

```
 app.post('/ai', (req, res) => {
  //console.log('*** Webhook for api.ai query ***');
  //console.log(req.body.result);

  if (req.body.result.action === 'weather') {
 //  console.log('*** weather ***');
    let city = req.body.result.parameters['geo-city'];
    let restUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID='+process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY+'&q='+city;

    request.get(restUrl, (err, response, body) => {
      if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
        let json = JSON.parse(body);
       // console.log(json);
        let tempF = ~~(json.main.temp * 9/5 - 459.67);
        let tempC = ~~(json.main.temp - 273.15);
        let msg = 'The current condition in ' + json.name + ' is ' + json.weather[0].description + ' and the temperature is ' + tempF + ' ℉ (' +tempC+ ' ℃).'
        return res.json({
          speech: msg,
          displayText: msg,
          source: 'weather'
        });
      } else {
        let errorMessage = 'I failed to look up the city name.';
        return res.status(400).json({
          status: {
            code: 400,
            errorType: errorMessage
          }
        });
      }
    })
  }

});
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the page-scoped ID you are sending with the message in `recipient.id` is not valid. Assuming you have set up the `sendMessage()` function from the tutorial corrently, most likely the problem is that the Facebook account you are using the chat with the bot does not have the proper role.

If the bot is not public (i.e. has not been submitted and approved) the Facebook account you are using to send messages to the bot has to be given the administrator, developer, or tester role in your app settings.